# Which offset does ctypes._FuncPtr accept as input?

Tags: python, ctypes, python-3.7

I am loading a dynamic library in python, for simplicity let's say glibc:

```py
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
```

Accessing functions from this library usually works by specifying a symbol, i.e.

```py
>>> libc.system(b"whoami")
```

The source for this function looks like this (from `/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py`):

```py
366     def __getattr__(self, name):
367         if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'):
368             raise AttributeError(name)
369         func = self.__getitem__(name)
370         setattr(self, name, func)                                                                                                                                                                              
371         return func
372 
373     def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
374         func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
375         if not isinstance(name_or_ordinal, int):
376             func.__name__ = name_or_ordinal
377         return func
```

So I suspect you could also specify an offset to call a function, i.e. something like this:

```py
>>> libc[0xabcd](b"foo")
```

However I always face the certain SEGFAULT when attempting to do that. I was wondering how I could retrieve the correct offset for a function?

In the case of glibc, simply looking up the symbols and passing their respective address does not seem to work. So I am probably missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the equivalent in Linux, but Windows has `dumpbin` to list a DLL's exports and the ordinal number of the export can be used:

```
C:\Windows\System32>dumpbin /exports msvcrt.dll|findstr system
       1024  3FF 00017DA0 _wsystem
       1249  4E0 00017EC0 system

C:\Windows\System32>py
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> crt = CDLL('msvcrt')
>>> crt[1249](b'echo hello')  # by ordinal
hello
0
>>> crt['system'](b'echo hello') # by name
hello
0
```